# Getting error 1822 in MySQL when trying to create a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am getting an error when creating a foreign key. The error is 1822 and it says the following:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'Changes_ibfk_4' in the referenced table 'Recipe'

I have read similar question and the problem seems to be, that the column that we need to create a foreign key on, does not have same datatype as the column that is referenced to.

However, I have no idea how the two columns are different to one another. Both are primary keys, with same name and type varchar(255). Below is the MySQL code.

Is there a difference between the two "version" columns? Or is the problem something else?

```
alter table Recipe drop column version;
alter table Changes drop column version;
alter table Recipe add column version varchar(255);
alter table Changes add column version varchar(255);
alter table Recipe drop primary key, add primary key(recipeID, version);
alter table Changes drop primary key, add primary key(newRecipeID, version);
alter table Changes add foreign key(version) references Recipe(version);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html in your example you have no such key in recipe for alter table Changes add foreign key(version) references Recipe(version

Comment: how would you create such an index? in the link you send me, it says that such index would be created automatically.

Comment: nevermind, i found out how. i first created an index by using "CREATE INDEX versionIndex ON Changes(version)" and then creating an index on version in Recipe by using the same syntax. But why didn't MySql create this automatically as it says in your link?

Comment: So it does but docs are wrong in this case and index will be created on changes(version) if it doesn't exist usually with a not very friendly name- you can see this on a show create table changes.