# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'student_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'instructor'

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

```
create database stmikglobal;
use stmikglobal;

create table depart(
    dept_name varchar(20) primary key,
    building varchar(20),
    budget float(15,2)
);

create table instructor(
    instruc_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ka_dept_name varchar(20),
    ins_name varchar(30) not null,
    salary int,
    foreign key (ka_dept_name) references depart (dept_name)
    );
    
    
    
create table student(
    id_stu int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ka_dept_name varchar (20),
    ka_ins_name varchar(30),
    full_name varchar(35),
    total_credits int,
    foreign key (ka_dept_name) references depart(dept_name),
    foreign key (ka_ins_name) references instructor(ins_name)
    );
```

why I want to executable in the table section there is a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error 1822 in MySQL when trying to create a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56078681/getting-error-1822-in-mysql-when-trying-to-create-a-foreign-key)

Answer (score 1):

You should be referencing the `instructor` table through its primary key (`instruc_id`) rather than by some other column (here, you used `ins_name`). So change the column name, datatype and foreign key declaration as follows:

```
create table student(
    id_stu int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ka_dept_name varchar (20),
    ka_instruc_id int,
    full_name varchar(35),
    total_credits int,
    foreign key (ka_dept_name) references depart(dept_name),
    foreign key (ka_instruc_id) references instructor(instruc_id)
);
```